# How to start node app with development flag?

Tags: node.js

At top of my app.js file I put

```
NODE_ENV='development';
```

but I get error that NODE_ENV is not defined. But in the nodejs documentation is says NODE_ENV is global. How can I start my app with development settings? Thank you.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It is better to start your app in dev mode like this:

```
NODE_ENV=development node app.js
```

But if you really wanted to set it your app file just set it like this:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV= "development"
```

Answer (score 5):

NODE_ENV is an *environment variable*.
You set it in your shell when you invoke Node.js.

However, development is the default; you only need to do anything if you want prod.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: (In Adam Sandler opera voice) That is very wrong-O! ...or at least in 2019-O. "development" is not default-O! I think this comment is done-O. Back to coding my app-O!

Answer (score 5):

If you want to set an environment variable in your **js** file you should do it this way:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';
```

Alternatively you can set the variable in your shell and run your application:

```
$ NODE_ENV="development" node ./app.js
```

or export the variable and run your application:

```
$ export NODE_ENV="development"
$ node ./app.js
```

On Windows:

```
$ set NODE_ENV="development"
$ node app.js
```

Answer (score 4):

By using NPM you might to be used the follow scripts in the package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon ./bin/www",
    "dev_win": "set NODE_ENV=development && node ./bin/www >> /romba/log/api.log 2>> /romba/log/error.log",
    "prod_win": "set NODE_ENV=production && node ./bin/www >> /romba/log/api.log 2>> /romba/log/error.log"
    "prod_nix": "NODE_ENV=production node ./bin/www >> /romba/log/api.log 2>> /romba/log/_error.log"
  },...
```

To start one of the script use the command:

```
 npm run-script prod_win
```

In the JavaScript code I check the condition:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV.indexOf('production') > -1
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to start from cmd you can try

```
NODE_ENV=development node yourappname.js
```

If you are doing this in server where [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) is installed you can mention the environment variable like

```
NODE_ENV=development forever start yourappname.js
```