# Debugging local nodejs script in chrome dev tools

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I have a stand alone node js script. 
I am doing some local task with that script. I want to debug that script in chrome dev tools. I know I can debug it locally via putting debugger in code but do not want to do that.

On nodejs docs I saw that it has some options like -

> V8 Inspector Integration for Node.js# NOTE: This is an experimental
>   feature.
>
> V8 Inspector integration allows attaching Chrome DevTools to Node.js
>   instances for debugging and profiling.
>
> V8 Inspector can be enabled by passing the --inspect flag when
>   starting a Node.js application. It is also possible to supply a custom
>   port with that flag, e.g. --inspect=9222 will accept DevTools
>   connections on port 9222.
>
> To break on the first line of the application code, provide the
>   --debug-brk flag in addition to --inspect.
>
> **$ node --inspect index.js**

But when I do that it gives me error like -

```
$ node --inspect index.js
node: bad option: --inspect
```

My node version is:

```
$ node --version
v4.4.7
```

Comment: Node 4 didn't have this experimental feature. It appeared in node 6. Probably you were reading latest docs. This one is for node 4: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/debugger.html

Comment: If you're running node.js v4 then [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) is worth a look

Comment: A related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19503641/465053) related to development/debugging in NodeJs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Andrey
Thanks a lot for pointing out that I was scratching my head for a long time on this.
@dan
Thanks for node-inspector suggestion.

I am just posting an answer in case someone else might stuck on this.

I have installed node-inspector and,

This is what I'm doing to start the debugger..
Opened one terminal and

```
$ node-inspector --no-preload
Node Inspector v0.12.5
Visit http://127.0.0.1:8080/?ws=127.0.0.1:8080&port=5858 to start debugging.
```

In another terminal,

```
$ node --debug-brk app.js 
debugger listening on port 5858
```

Intially I was using just `--debug`. But it was not hitting the breakpoints and was going through all code. Then I used `--debug-brk`. Using `--debug-brk` caused node to break on the first line of app and waited for a debugger to hit breakpoints.

Then started Google Chrome and went to 
http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?port=5858

Here chrome dev tools was opened and I was able to put break point and debug the code.

Answer (score 8):

You need node 6.3 or above --inspect is not supported in 4.4.7

Comment: That can’t be true. I got node 14 and get the same message.

Answer (score 0):

Node Inspector works pretty well. Also keep in mind Node 7 has native node debugging, even supports live-edit! Here's a gif of it in action: [Chrome DevTools: Live edit running Node.js code with hotswapping](https://umaar.com/dev-tips/119-node-js-hot-code-swap/)